# reversed counting in django template with <ol>-tag

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I want to write a template which

- is paginated (not all list items on the same page)
- is numbered with -tag because this is the most semantic way to order the list
- can be reversed or not
- the numbers are linked to the represented models (every `li`-tag contains an `a`-tag that is linked to a model.) That means the list not alway starts with 1.

---

My model:

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):
  number = positiveIntegerField() 
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  [...]
```

`number` is unique, ordered and when you order the models with the number, there is no gap; number is 1-based

---

What I have: (`reverse` is boolean variable which tells whether the list has to be reversed or not)

```
{% if reverse %}
<ol class="content" start="{{ article_list.0.number|add:article_list.count }}" reversed=true>
    {% for article in article_list reversed %}
        <li class="{% cycle '' '' '' '' 'seperate-bot border-gray' %}"><a href="{% url 'myapp:article' article.number %}">{{ article.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
<ol class="content" start="{{ article_list.0.number }}">
    {% for article in article_list %}
        <li class="{% cycle '' '' '' '' 'seperate-bot border-gray' %}"><a href="{% url 'manifest:article' article.number %}">{{ article.alt_title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
</ol>
```

---

Unfortunately counts the backward template part wrong: the last number is always 1 which it shouldn't be. The last number should be `article_list.0.number` + `article_list.count` (or: `article_list|length`) -`1`; or `last_list_item.number` that would be better.

That means: (paginated_by = 3 for that example) the "|" because SO changes my counting
**How it should be:** (reverse=true)

*page 1*:

|3. lorem ipsum

|2. lorem ipsum

|1. lorem ipsum

*page 2*:

|5. lorem ipsum

|4. lorem ipsum

**What I get**: (only page 2 is bad)

*page 2*:

|2. lorem ipsum

|1. lorem ipsum

---

Is there a good way to avoid that effect? (And where does it come from?) In the best case that should work in the template only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would get that result, but this seems like a overly complicated way to do something quite straightforward.

You can use the built in `last` filter and `with` template tag to access the last item in a list.

```
{% with article_list|last as last_article %}
<ol class="content" start="{{ last_article.number }}" reversed=true>
{% endwith %}
```

However, I would recommend you do the ordering and reversing in the view function instead of in the template. Django's template language is by choice not suited for non trivial logic.

As for the numbering, you can actually explicitly assign a value attribute to a ordered list element. This would solve your problem.

```
<li value={{ article.number }} ...
```

Example:

```html
<ol>
  <li value=3>it doesn't
  <li>have to
  <li>make
  <li value=42>sense
</ol>
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know there is something like `value`, and the reason, why not to do this in the view, is, if I had overriden `get_queryset` there would have been other entries on the current page.